# Progress Circle Completion

Tags: css, geometry, progress, calculation

I am attempting to create an equation or method of completing the circle based on percentage.

Here is what I have:

[image]

I would like to be able to complete the circle based on percentage increase and have it start on the side like the image below:
[image]

[image]

I am trying to get the alignment to be similar but I am having no luck with that or the calculation.

Here is my code:

```css
#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 span {
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 123%;
  height: 123%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

svg circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #191919;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: translate(-28px, -28px);
}

svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: calc( 440 - (440 * 90) / 100);
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="percent">
        <svg>
                      <!-- <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle> -->

                      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%"></circle>
                      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%"></circle>
                    </svg>
        <div class="number">
          <h2>60<span>%</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="text">69 of 115 Goals Completed</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are problems both of alignment and of setting the dash length on the second circle.

It looks as though the original code used the first circle to fill the second but it has been made redundant by the circular div percentage.
Alignment is off because the circle has radius 40% inside an svg of diameter 123% which sets it off from this circular div.
An attempt has been made to realign by translating -23px
Simplifying we draw just one svg circle which will have the percentage green border and make sure it is exactly over the div percentage

Now we come to the calculation of the green bar that will show the %
The CSS has a calc which looks like an attempt to calculate the dash size for a 90% score.
But it doesn't look like legal CSS (needs to be a calc for every calculation to be performed).
And the CSS also has a fixed 440 which is roughly a representation of 60% not of the whole circle.
Starting from scratch on these two settings, we need the dash to be n% of the circumference of the circle.
So we calculate the circumference of the circle then this % of it and draw that length with a gap of cicumference - length.

Note - because you can get edge effects on curves with borders or shadows, the background of the dark circle has been changed to a radial-gradient image with slightly smaller radius.

This snippet has an additional input element where you can put in the number of goals reached to check that the green arc goes to the right length.

```js
document.querySelector('.goals').addEventListener('change', function(){
    var goals = parseInt(this.value);
    var circle = document.querySelector('circle');
    var percentdiv = document.querySelector('.percent');
    var completed = document.querySelector('.completed');
    completed.innerHTML = goals;
    var totaldiv = document.querySelector('.total');
    var total = totaldiv.innerHTML;
    var pc = goals*100/total;
    var r = circle.getAttribute('r').replace('%','')*percentdiv.clientWidth/100;//actual radius of the circle
    var c = Math.PI*(r*2);//circumference is 2*pi*r
    
    if (isNaN(goals)) { pc = 100; }
    else if (pc < 0) { pc = 0;}
    else if (pc > 100) { pc = 100;}
    document.querySelector('.number h2').innerHTML = Math.floor(pc) + '<span>%</span>';

    var length = pc * c/100;
        
    circle.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + (c-length);
    circle.style.strokeWidth = (length > 0) ? '5%': 0;
});
```

```css
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
        #progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  rbox-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#444 0%, #222 70%, transparent 70%, transparent 100%);
  rbackground: #222;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 span {
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

svg circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="percent">
                      <svg>
                      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="47.5%"></circle>
                    </svg>
        <div class="number">
          <h2>0<span>%</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="text"><span class="completed">0</span> of <span class="total">115</span> Goals Completed</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Goals completed: <input class="goals" type='number'/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to remove the "Goals completed: <input class="goals" type='number'/>" so that I can just update the progress by changing the static value of "goals" in the code? I want to be able to pull information from an external source. I do not want there to be a prompt that says "Goals completed" or an area that the user has to update.